# Valid files are not being opened in C

Tags: c, file-io

I'm working on a final project and the FILE I/O portion is being particularly difficult.
The issue: when I read a base file which tells me how many savefiles have already been created I ask the user to choose from these savefiles if the maximum number of files have been created. In this case the user has the option of 3 save files. Afterwards i pass the name of the file in the format of a string into a fcn that writes into the file. However the issue is that despite passing valid file names the fopen fcn returns NULL to the file pointer. Why is this?

What i've tried so far:

- I've already tried closing all data files
- I am not using other versions that use the same code which may have the files already open.
- the data files can be opened individually
- the filenames are also valid

  ```
  void WriteSaveFile (char s[], struct boardType *board, enum gameStatusType *status){
      char temp [MAX_LENGTH];//doesn't create things.txt or 123456.txt 
      printf ("%s",s);

      FILE * wp = fopen (s,"w");
      if (wp==NULL)
          printf ("error\n");
      fprintf (wp,"bruh");
      fclose (wp);    

      FILE *rp = fopen (s,"r");
      if (fgets (temp, 60, rp) !=NULL)
          printf ("%s",temp);
      else printf ("woops");
          fclose (rp);
  }
  ```

Comment: This piece of code works fine for me. Are you sure that string s doesn't contain some strange characters?

Comment: What valid file names are you passing?  What is the environment in which you are running the programs?  Are you sure that the relative names are relative to the correct directory?  Have you tried printing `fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));` when `fopen()` fails (you'll need `<string.h>` and `<errno.h>` as headers). If you're on a POSIX-ish system, have you tried printing the result of `getcwd()` in the running program?

Comment: I used fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", strerror(errno)); and it returns "error invalid argument". Does that mean that the file path is invalid?

Comment: `if (wp==NULL) printf ("error\n"); fprintf (wp,"bruh"); fclose (wp);` invokes UB if `wp==NULL)`.  Suggest `if (wp==NULL) { printf ("error\n"); return; } fprintf (wp,"bruh"); fclose (wp);`

Comment: Check return value of `FILE *rp = fopen (s,"r");`

Comment: Further to @pwwpche's comment, I'd be willing to wager a little money that the string (`s[]`) has a newline character at the end.  `printf("%sXXX", s)` ought to show you if it has a newline or not.

Comment: @Tony I added a '\n' to the end of "123456.txt", and it does print "error". Maybe this is why Nubail's function works fine for me :).